# pods "istio-operator-7448dbfb5-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, kubernetes-pod, podsecuritypolicy

I am facing this error with "istio-operator" after upgrading the gke cluster from 1.16.15-gke.7800 to 1.17.17-gke.3700 and this error is appearing only in a few clusters, not with all the 1.17 GKE cluster.

Comment: Can you add the whole error from the logs? You use istio OOS or gke addon? What is your istio version?

Comment: pods "istio-operator-7448dbfb5-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [] " and it is gke addon and istio-security-post-install-1.4.10-gke.8  @Jakub